# ArcMap freezes when drawing layout at smaller scale (with ArcGIS online imagery)

Tags: layouts, zoom, arcgis-online-basemaps

In layout view, when I change to a smaller scale (i.e., from 1"=80' to 1"=60'), the imagery basemap from ArcGIS online draws (seems to be complete) but no other layers draw. ArcMap, at that point is frozen, and I have to force quit the application. There are only a few other layers and they are small and local.

ArcMap will draw the same combination of layers in data view at any scale without problem. This only seems to happen in layout view.

I'm using ArcMap 10.8.1.

Comment: It seems like this question would be more appropriate for ESRI support. I am not sure that anyone would be able to replicate this issue and troubleshoot for you on Stack Exchange.

Comment: I have a lot of problems changing scale with a basemap in ArcMap and find it works better in other software.  It's been that way for some time.  I think the ESRI suggestion would be to add the map from the ArcGIS rest servers: http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/.  Use World Imagery.